# How to securely store SSN details in a database while maintaining searches?

Tags: encryption

My question is very similar to [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59580/how-to-safely-store-sensitive-data-like-a-social-security-number), but in my situation I do not need to recover the real value. My concern with just hashing the value is that since there's a finite and (relatively) small number of SSNs possible is that it would be too easy to brute force SSNs.

The SSN will really just be used as a lookup value for **multiple** records. My idea is to have the application server hash the plaintext SSN using a slow algorithm like PBKDF2 with a static salt. The application server sends this data to the crypto server, which encrypts the data with AES-256 in CBC mode with a static IV. The encrypted data is then hashed with SHA-256, and this is inserted into the database as a hex string.

Here's a flow diagram:[image: flow diagram]

I believe this to be a very secure model since the attacker would need to brute force:

1. The encrypted data (256 bits minimum!)
2. The IV (128 bits minimum. This can be arbitrarily large so long as its length is a multiple of the block size (16))
3. The key (another 256 bits)
4. The SSN salt (can be arbitrarily large)
5. The SSN (1000000000 options – very fast to compute but with a slow hashing algorithm it'll take a while to get all of them)

As somewhat of an aside, my coworker has two concerns of his own:

1. He wants to ensure that there are no duplicate ciphertexts in the DB
2. Searches. He had looked at some papers which described searchable symmetric encryption ([link 1](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/popa-multikey-eprint.pdf), [link 2](http://outsourcedbits.org/2014/08/21/how-to-search-on-encrypted-data-searchable-symmetric-encryption-part-5/), [link 3](http://bristolcrypto.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-search-on-encrypted-data-in.html)).

My response to #1 is that this would require being able to recover the plaintext SSN, which an attacker would also be able to do.

And for #2, I am not a cryptographer but my reasoning for shutting down this ideas is that I for one do not know of any implemented and thoroughly tested algorithms/libraries supporting this, and these enable "keyword" search. Depending on how that works, the keyword in this context would be the SSN and I really cannot see how it would complicate things with querying the database.

This is a fairly loaded question, but is my model secure and are my points accurate?

Comment: Please read: http://serverfault.com/questions/162214/do-we-have-to-be-pci-compliant-to-store-social-security-numbers-in-our-hosted-da .. i.e. "if located in the United States, you will likely be subject to state and federal laws by storing the social security number and I would suggest you treat it as PCI scope data."

Comment: @ekaj I'm not sure how this helps me.

Comment: @downvoter: why?